# Javascript Array if is null error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `this.entries = []`. I run some code and it runs through this `if` statement several times:

```
if(this.entries[2] != null)
```

Everything works fine until after all the code runs I reset the array:

I've tried doing `this.entries = []` and `this.entries.splice(0, this.entries.length);`

I re-run the code and when it gets to the `if` statement I get this error:

```
Cannot read property '2' of null
```

As far as I can tell there is nothing different. Tips and help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your whole function please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several objects here.  There is `this`  which of course should never be `null`.  Then there is `this.entries`  Which is an array.  Think of it as a container that can contain things.  Then, there is `this.entries[i]`  Which are the things in the container.

when `this.entries[2]` fails, it means that there is no object in slot 2 of the container.

However, the error `Cannot read property '2' of null`  means that there IS NO CONTAINER.  That is, the array itself has been set to null.

Comment: Javascript allows you to access an array out of bounds - it gives back `undefined` for reads and resizes the array for writes. There is no such thing as a "null error" in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It seems I had accidentally set the entries to null somewhere else and that was what caused it to crash.